# Modify file permissions for files created with php

Tags: php, linux, apache, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

I use the tensorflow based program luminoth for object detection. To execute luminoth while it is installed on a server i use php. When luminoth starts the prediction, it creates a file named `objects.json`. In the end, it writes the result in this objects.json file. But when i execute it via php the prediction stops before writing the result. The permissions of the objects.json file are `-rw-r--w--`

I think it is because this permissions do not allow luminoth to write the result in this file. Do you think I am right? I tried to set permissions like

```sh
chmod 2777 /var/www/html
```

to test, but it does not work.
I wrote in my sudoers file:

```
%www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I hope that I am right. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, touch the file:

```
touch objects.json
```

Then give only the permission it really needs:

```
chmod 644 objects.json
```

Maybe if you need, also set the correct owner:

```
chown user:group objects.json
```

Then execute your script:

```
php bin/run.php
```

Don't pass chmod `777` tryhard getting something to work. Use only the permission you need.

[image]

*) Image source: http://thisismao.com/wordpress/the-777-developer/

Answer (score -1):

Try this (change path accordingly

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/{path}/objects.json
```

Comment: this gives premission to an existing file, but with each prediction the objects.json is created new. and is again -rw-r--w--

Comment: Why do you give execute bit to a json file? Why open permission for the whole server? Why do you use recursive flag on a single file?